# Nothing I try will make my Sony xperia x connect to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, sony-xperia

I have tried everything that every source I can find has suggested: enabled developer mode and usb debugging (and stay awake while plugged in), I installed the USB drivers and even tried the xperia x specific usb drivers, I have tried all the different connection modes (MTP and PTP, for some reason couldnt find MSC).  And yet my phone doesnt show up in the list of devices on android studio.

I did see an article that mentioned removing previous drivers or something, would that mean getting rid of the xperia companion that my phone installed to my PC?

Comment: Use [Universal ADB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/). Then connect your phone.

Comment: That worked thanks! :)

Comment: Add a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to your question. So that the Community will mark this thread as completed.

Comment: I had the same experience as Chris and Shashanth's solution helped me as well.  Thank you!